# Homeomorphism between a semicircle and a line

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, circles

I'm trying to prove a homeomorphism between a circle and a square.

My idea is to use the function $\theta(x,y) = \dfrac{(x,y)}{\max(\mid x\mid, \mid y \mid)}$  and slice the square and circle into 4 pieces, similar to [this](http://eprints.utm.my/id/eprint/10096/1/AmidoraIdris2008_HomeomorphismBetweenSphereandCube.pdf) article .

Do you have any suggestions on how to prove the injectivity and surjectivity of the semicircle with one of the sides of the square?

I can't think of anything that relates them

[image]

Comment: For the picture you have drawn, have you considered projection onto the $y$ axis? The map $(x,y)\mapsto y$ is a homeomorphism between the quarter circle and the vertical line

Comment: You should write down explicitly what are domain and range of $\theta$.

Comment: @Aidan, No, I just conjectured that the homeomorphism must be between the green and red lines. However, I cannot prove that this is true or that it is a lie.

Comment: @GlebersonAntunes Well, projection onto the y coordinate is continuous, and clearly surjective. For a quarter circle, x is determined by y, so it is injective. The inverse (for the picture given) would be like ($\sqrt{1-y^2}$,y), which you can show to be continuous

Comment: You could use the fact that $S^1 \setminus {x}$ (homeomorphic to a line segment) is homeomorphic to $S^1 \setminus y_i$ for some $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$(essentially the semicircle)

Answer (score 1):

The approach in the linked paper is far too complicated. You do not need any pieces.

Let us construct a homeomorphism between the sphere $S^n = \{x \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \mid \lVert x \rVert_2 = 1\}$ and the surface $C^n$ of the $(n+1)$-dimensional solid cube $[-1,1]^{n+1}$. Note that both $S^n,C^n$ receive the subspace topology from $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

$\lVert - \rVert_2 : \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$ is the Euclidean norm given by $\lVert (x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}) \rVert_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i^2}$. This is clearly a continuous function.

Moreover, let $\lVert - \rVert_\infty : \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R, \lVert (x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}) \rVert_\infty = \max(\lvert x_1 \rvert, \ldots, \lvert x_{n+1} \rvert)$. This function is continuous; it is known as the maximum norm. Recall that $C^n = [-1,1]^{n+1} \setminus (-1,1)^{n+1}$. Clearly $[-1,1]^{n+1} = \{x \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \mid \lVert x \rVert_\infty \le 1\}$ and $(-1,1)^{n+1} = \{x \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \mid \lVert x \rVert_\infty < 1\}$, thus $C^n = \{x \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \mid \lVert x \rVert_\infty = 1\}$.

Define
$$\phi : S^n \to C^n, \phi(x) = \frac{x\phantom{x}}{\lVert x \rVert_\infty}.$$
This is well-defined since $\lVert x \rVert_\infty \ne 0$ for $x \ne 0$ and $\left\lVert  \frac{x\phantom{x}}{\lVert x \rVert_\infty} \right\rVert_\infty = \frac{\lVert x \rVert_\infty}{\lVert x \rVert_\infty} = 1$. Clearly $\phi$ is continuous.

Similarly
$$\psi : C^n \to S^n, \psi(x) = \frac{x\phantom{x}}{\lVert x \rVert_2}$$
is a well-defined continuous function.

But now we have
$$\psi(\phi(x)) =  \frac{\frac{x\phantom{x}}{\lVert x \rVert_\infty}}{\left\lVert\frac{x\phantom{x}}{\lVert x \rVert_\infty }\right\rVert_2} = \frac{\frac{x\phantom{x}}{\lVert x \rVert_\infty}}{\frac{\lVert x\rVert_2}{\lVert x \rVert_\infty }} = \frac{x\phantom{x}}{\lVert x\rVert_2} = x$$

since $\lVert x \rVert_2 =1 $ for $x \in S^n$. Similarly $\phi(\psi(x)) = x$.

This shows that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are inverse to each other which means that both maps are homeomorphisms such that $\psi = \phi^{-1}$.